# Virtual network between Hyper-V host and guest VM is blocked by firewall because marked as unidentified

Tags: hyper-v, windows-firewall, virtual-network

I have the following setup:

- Windows machine with Hyper-V activated
- Hyper-V VM under CentOS 7 using the default virtual switch as an interface between host and guest
- The virtual switch has `172.24.255.1` address on host (Windows)
- I manually configured `172.24.255.2` as IP address and `172.24.255.1` as gateway on guest

With this setup, my guest machine is able to connect to the internet. Now I'm trying to share a Windows directory and access it on the guest machine.

I've lost a couple of hours after finding out that my firewall was blocking everything from the virtual switch, because it's not considered as Domain, Private or Public, it's tagged "Unidentified network". How do I make this network trusted by Windows?

Comment: I get the same problem, after I turn off firewall, my guest VM can ping my host windows PC. I think that this is a bug, there should be at least an option to say "Allow the guest VM access my host network".

Answer (score 1):

Unidentified network means that the adapter is not connected to the internet. Can you make sure that the Virtual Switch Manager is set to External Network and the interface that is selected is connected to the network. Sounds like you have it set to internal network and are manually setting the ip address. If you set it to external network, just allow the CentOS server to get an ip address from DHCP.

[image: Switch Manager]